# GPS Data string to Associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert below GPS device data string

```
{"alarm":"input2Inactive","odometer":594,"rssi":0,"sat":0,"status":0,"input":0,"output":0,"adc1":2437,"adc2":331,"adc3":117,"driverUniqueId":"1","distance":0.0,"totalDistance":270.03,"motion":false}
```

to an associative array like below array code

```
$array = array("alarm" => "input2Inactive","odometer" => "594","rssi" => "0","sat" => "0","status" => "0","input" => "0","output" => "0","adc1" => "2437","adc2" => "331","adc3" => "117","driverUniqueId" => "1","distance" => "0.0","totalDistance" => "270.03","motion" => "false");
```

Comment: $dataValue = json_decode($data,true);